# How to upload files with inertia js and laravel 8.0

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I have an update ( patch form ) that can have some basic fields with one featured image and an array of gallery images.

```
updatePhotoPreview(event) {
   this.featuredImagePreview = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
   this.updateProductForm.featured_image = event.target.files[0]
},
```

Before sending the request and even in the request header, the featured image is File and binary.

Then I'm simply posting the form with `this.form.patch(url)`.

I'm getting an error the featured_image must be an image.

I've dumped the request and somehow my featured_image value has been[image] set to an empty array.

The same is for the gallery images, it has been turned into an array of empty arrays.

I've tried changing the route to post, put, the result is the same, I've added a custom header

```
 { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} }
```

The result is the same.

but the same form is working for the create endpoint of this resource with POST method.
I've removed all the request classes and dumping with `request()->all()`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to upload a photo via InertiaJS and Laravel 8 following the steps below:

1. In our VueJS component's `HTML`:

```
<input type="file" class="hidden"
             ref="photo"
             @change="updatePreview">
<div v-show="preview">
  <span class="block w-20 h-20 rounded-full"
        :style="'width: 5rem; height: 5rem; border-radius: 999px; display: block; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-image: url(\'' + photoPreview + '\');'">
  </span>
</div>
```

2. In our `methods` object:

```
updatePhotoPreview() {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        this.preview = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(this.$refs.photo.files[0]);
},
storePhoto() {
    if (this.$refs.photo) {
        this.form.photo = this.$refs.photo.files[0]
    }

    this.form.post(route('photo.store'), {
        preserveScroll: true
    });
},
```

3. In our `data` function:

```
data() {
   return {
       form: this.$inertia.form({
           '_method': 'PUT',
           photo: null,
       }, {
           resetOnSuccess: false,
       }),
       preview: null,
   }
},
```

4. In our Laravel `Controller`:

```
class PhotoController 
{
    public function store(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'image', 'max:1024'],
        ]);

        if (isset($input['photo'])) {
           $photo->storePublicly();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect with `form.post` and add `'_method': 'PUT'` to params.. Thank you!

Comment: Always happy to help @MrEduar ! :)

Comment: When I add this I am getting, `The PUT method is not supported for route pateints/create. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST`

Answer (score 2):

I fix this by adding '_method' on form and using 'post' request.

```
data() {
    return {
        form: this.$inertia.form({
            _method: "PUT",
        })
    };
},
methods: {
    submit(form) {
        this.form
            .post("route/id", form, {
                preserveState: true
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add this I am getting, `The PUT method is not supported for route pateints/create. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST`

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = new FormData()
data.append('first_name', first_name || '')
data.append('last_name', last_name || '')
data.append('email', email || '')
data.append('password', password || '')
data.append('photo', photo || '')

Inertia.post('/users', data)
```

Try this. Just use FormData() instantiation

Please refer the documentation https://inertiajs.com/forms#file-uploads

Answer (score -1):

use formData

```js
const fd = new FormData()

fd.append('file', this.form.file)

this.$inertia.post(route('file.register'), fd)
```